# What is the best practice for saving a file in janusgraph?

Tags: file, graph-databases, gremlin, tinkerpop3, janusgraph

I am developing my backend application in java using JanusGraph database version 0.3.1 . I want to manage the saved files as properties for vertex in the graph.

1- Can I save images, xml files, text file, etc. in JanusGraph properties?

2- Is it a good practice to save text files in string property and what about images and audios ...

3- Do big files slows down the search performance ?

I tried to save a png file in vertex property using byte array datatype it worked but I am getting now serialization exception in gremlin server  when querying this vertex.

**Edit**
I saved the image with transformation to base64 encoding.

Comment: Have you considered using a document database for that? Take a look at OrientDB, it's advertised as a mix of a graph and document DB.